# Internet Explorer 9 in compatibility-mode shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

While testing my jQuery script in IE 9 it shows error in jquery-1.6.2.js --

```
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught 
jquery-1.6.2.js, line 548 character 3
```

My js file used to work with no problems in other browsers - firefox 3.6, 5.0, opera 11, chromium, chrome. I do not understand. Is there a bug in the jquery source or is there a bug in my js file ? How do I find it ?

It hasen't been long since I started in this area so please I would really appreciate some ideas.

Thank you in advance.

[edited]
I've added the complete code.
I've learnt from :
 http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-jquery-image-cropping-plug-in-from-scratch-part-ii/

I don't know which part to add. The whole code does not fit in stackoverflow's submit. says "body is limited to 3000 characters; you entered 42121 "

[2nd edit]
I have used 'error' in my ajax submit.

```
    //jquery ajax submit for resizing
    function submit(myform,e){
        $n.val($image.attr('src').replace(/^[^,]*\//,''));

        var mydata = myform.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: $myform.attr('action'),
            cache: false,
            type:$myform.attr('method'),
            data: mydata,

            success: function(response){
                var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'images/'+response+'?'+ e.timeStamp) //<-- img name here
                    .load(function() {
                       if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                           alert('Incorrect image.');

                       } else {
                           $("#result").html(img); //<-- put cropped img here.

                       }
                    });


                    },
            error: function(){ //<-- error used here
                        $('#result').html("Err. Loading Image");
                    }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Are my code required ? I am creating a jQuery Plugin and I don't know from where the error got generated.

Comment: your code would be nice to see :)

Comment: The error-handler above could not be the reason, it's a different thing than jQuery.error()

Comment: Does it matter if IE9 shows an error in compatibility mode? Just make sure your documents are all in standard mode, and you can ignore it.

Comment: That is also a good point. Reason I did it was to test my code in older IE versions (<9). I have version 9 installed in my machine. Else, I will need to go hunting for a machine in my neighborhood with older IE. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I traced out my problem. IE prevented changing of attribute which let to the jQuery error.

```
 Note: jQuery prohibits changing the type attribute on an or element and
 will throw an error in all browsers. This is because the type attribute 
 cannot be changed in Internet Explorer."
```

from [http://api.jquery.com/attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), just after 1st warning notice.

So I changed my code from earlier

```
$('input').clone()
```

to

```
$('<input />').attr({'type':'hidden'})
```

and it solved my problem.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but do you somewhere use $.error() inside your code? If yes: don't use it.

---

```
<edit>
```

However, this error comes from [jQuery.error()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.error/).

The original error-function looks like this:

```
error: function( msg ) {
        throw msg;
    }
```

You may test it without jquery:

```
(function( msg ) {
        throw msg;
    })('errormessage');
```

You'll get the same error.

If you don't use `jQuery.error()` maybe you use some plugin that uses it.
You may override this (buggy?) function by executing the following right after the embedded jquery.js:

```
jQuery.error=function(){}

</edit>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`jQuery.error()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L527) (which `throws` the message passed as an argument), is totally different to the `error` handler specified in an AJAX call.

`jQuery.error()` is used [internally by `jQuery`](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js) (search for "error("). You should debug your code and follow the stack trace to find which of your methods is calling the jQuery method which is erroring.